# On-demand Median Aggregation on a Large Dataset

Tags: postgresql, bigdata, amazon-redshift, rdbms, datastore

**TLDR: I need to make several median aggregations on a large dataset for a webapp, but the performance is poor. Can my query be improved/is there a better DB than AWS Redshift for this use-case?**

I'm working on a team project which involves on-demand aggregations of a large dataset for visualization through our web-app. We're using Amazon Redshift loaded with almost 1,000,000,000 rows, dist-key by date (we have data from 2014 up to today's date, with 900,000 data points being ingested every day) and sort-key by a unique id. The unique id has a possibly one-to-many relationship with other unique ids, for which the 'many' relationship can be thought as the id's 'children'.

Due to confidentiality, think of the table structures like this

```
TABLE NAME: meal_nutrition
DISTKEY(date),
SORTKEY(patient_id),
patient_name varchar,
calories integer,
fat integer,
carbohydrates integer,
protein integer,
cholesterol integer,
sodium integer,
calories integer

TABLE NAME: patient_hierarchy
DISTKEY(date date),
SORTKEY(patient_id integer),
parent_id integer,
child_id integer,
distance integer
```

Think of this as a world for which there's a hierarchy of doctors. Patients are encapsulated as both actual patients and the doctors themselves, for which doctors can be the patient of other doctors. Doctors can transfer ownership of patients/doctors at any time, so the hierarchy is constantly changing.

```
     DOCTOR (id: 1)
      /         \
PATIENT(id: 2) DOCTOR (id: 3)
              /        \      \
       P (id: 4)    D (id: 8) D(id: 20)
                     /  \     / \ / \ \
            ................
```

One visualization that we're having trouble with (due to performance) is a time-series graph showing the day-to-day median of several metrics for which the default date-range must be 1 year. So in this example, we want the median of fats, carbohydrates, and proteins of all meals consumed by a patient/doctor and their 'children', given a patient_id. The query used would be:

```
SELECT patient_name,
    date,
    max(median_fats),
    max(median_carbs),
    max(median_proteins)
FROM (SELECT mn.date date,
    ph.patient_name patient_name,
    MEDIAN(fats) over (PARTITION BY date) AS median_fats,
    MEDIAN(carbohydrates) over (PARTITION BY date) AS median_carbs,
    MEDIAN(proteins) over (PARTITION BY date) AS median_proteins
        FROM meal_nutrition mn
        JOIN patient_hierarchy ph
        ON (mn.patient_id = ph.child_id)
        WHERE ph.date = (SELECT max(date) FROM patient_hierarchy)
        AND ph.parent_id = ?
        AND date >= '2016-12-17' and date <= '2017-12-17'
)
GROUP BY date, patient_name
```

The heaviest operations in this query are the sorts for the each of the medians (each requiring to sort ~200,000,000 rows), but we cannot avoid this. As a result, this query takes ~30s to complete, which translates to bad UX. Can the query I'm making be improved? Is there a better DB for this kind of use-case? Thanks!

Comment: Don't distribute on a date, distribute on the join columns. Use the date as the sort key. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-engineerings-advanced-table-design-playbook-preamble-prerequisites-and-prioritization/

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, sorting/distribution of your data is very important. If you get just one date slice of patient hierarchy all data you're using is on one node with distribution by date. It's better to distribute by `meal_nutrition.patient_id` and `patient_hierarchy.child_id` so data that is joined likely sits on the same node, and sort tables by `date,patient_id` and `date,child_id` respectively, so you can find the necessary date slices/ranges efficiently and then look up for patients efficiently.

As for the query itself, there are some options that you can try:

1) Approximate median like this:

```
SELECT mn.date date,
ph.patient_name patient_name,
APPROXIMATE PERCENTILE_DISC (0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fats) AS median_fats
FROM meal_nutrition mn
JOIN patient_hierarchy ph
ON (mn.patient_id = ph.child_id)
WHERE ph.date = (SELECT max(date) FROM patient_hierarchy)
AND ph.parent_id = ?
AND date >= '2016-12-17' and date <= '2017-12-17'
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Notes: this might not work if the memory stack is exceeded. Also, you have to have only one such function per subquery so you can't get fats, carbs and proteins in the same subquery but you can calculate them separately and then join. if this works you can then test the accuracy by running your 30s statement for a few IDs and comparing results.

2) Binning. First group by each value, or set reasonable bins, then find the group/bin that is in the middle of the distribution. That will be your median. One variable example would be:

```
WITH
groups as (
    SELECT mn.date date,
    ph.patient_name patient_name,
    fats,
    count(1)
    FROM meal_nutrition mn
    JOIN patient_hierarchy ph
    ON (mn.patient_id = ph.child_id)
    WHERE ph.date = (SELECT max(date) FROM patient_hierarchy)
    AND ph.parent_id = ?
    AND date >= '2016-12-17' and date <= '2017-12-17'
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
,running_groups as (
    SELECT *
    ,sum(count) over (partition by date, patient_name order by fats rows between unlimited preceding and current row) as running_total
    ,sum(count) (partition by date, patient_name) as total
    FROM groups
)
,distance_from_median as (
    SELECT *
    ,row_number() over (partition by date, patient_name order by abs(0.5-(1.0*running_total/total))) as distance_from_median
    FROM running_groups
)
SELECT
date,
patient_name,
fats
WHERE distance_from_median=1
```

That would likely allow grouping values on each individual node and subsequent operations with bins will be more light weight and avoid sorting the raw sets. Again, you have to benchmark. The less unique values you have the higher your performance gain will be because you'll have a small number of bins out of a big number of raw values and sorting will be much cheaper. The result is accurate except the option with even number of distinct values (for `1,2,3,4` it would return 2, not 2.5) but this is solvable by adding another layer if it's critical. The main question is if the approach itself improves performance significantly.

3) Materialize calculation for every date/patient id. If your only parameter is patient and you always calculate medians for the last year you can run the query overnight into a summary table and query that one. It's better even if (1) or (2) helps to optimize performance. You can also copy the summary table to a Postgres instance after materializing and use it as the backend for your app, you'll have better ping (Redshift is good for materializing large amounts of data but not good as web app backend). It comes with the cost of maintaining data transfer job, so if materializing/optimization made a good enough job you can leave it in Redshift.

I'm really interested in getting feedback if you try any of suggested options, this is a good use case for Redshift.